# Why do my Pyinstaller created .exe files keep crashing on start-up

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have written different Python projects using PyQT5 and now trying to create their .exe files to make them standalone and executable but whenever I try using pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py
```

the created .exe file always crashes. But in my other system, when  create .exe files using the same pyinstaller command, the .exe files run well. So why am I having issues creating .exe files in this particular system? What could be wrong please? My files contains python classes of different widgets and the scripts run well in the editors, the GUIs open well when run from the editor but not as a standalone. Now I want them as standalone. I have also used auto-py-to-exe, same issue. How do I resolve this?

I am also attaching a screenshot of the pyinstaller details of both systems to this post. The two descriptions (details) are captured in the photo, the one on the larger screen is the one of the system I am having issues with, while the smaller display is the one of the system where the .exe files are created and runs successfully without any issue. I noticed in the one running successfully, the attributes are more compared to the one having an issue. The one without an issue has [recursive-copy meta data],[splash image file], [disable windowed traceback], [--target -architecture arch], [-codesign identity IDENTITY], [--osx-entitlements-filename-FILENAME] whereas the pyinstaller having issues in my other system does not have it.

[image: a screenshot of pyinstaller attributes]

The below is some of the errors I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
  exec(line)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\importlib\util.py", line 2, in <module>
  from . import abc
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 17, in <module>
  from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
  class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
  self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of f:\installed program files\python\python 
39\lib\site-packages\zope.event-4.5.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\site.py", line 
 169, in addpackage
  exec(line)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\importlib\util.py", line 2, in <module>
  from . import abc
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\importlib\abc.py", 
line 17, in <module>
  from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
  class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
File "f:\installed program files\python\python 39\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
  self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to it and hope others having similar issue who come across this post will use the suggestion too. I had to pip uninstall typing. i.e

```
pip uninstall typing
```

This helps fix whatever issue there was and my .exe files run well using pyinstaller without crashing. After uninstalling typing module, run the pyinstaller command again to create your executables.

Comment: To be clear, if you're running Python 3.9 you should not even have a third-party "typing" package installed, since it's part of the standard library.

Comment: Hello @Iguananaut, I remember I had an issue with python 3.9.4, the pip version was 21.x.y, I experience issue with that pip version as it doesn't allow me install any module. I had to downgrade to pip version 20.3.y. Python 3.7 doesn't have issue with pip because the pip version is below 21

Comment: pip doesn't have a dependency on the typing module and does not include or install it in any way.